# What is significance of the red star in the Reputation bar of the Squad screen?

Tags: mass-effect-3

What is the meaning of this red star found in Shepard's reputation bar in the Squad menu?

[image: Shepard's reputation bar]

Comment: They are not mutually exclusive. Not in ME3 anyway.

Comment: @JamesJiao What do you mean?

Comment: Renegade and Paragon points are not mutually exclusive. They can coexist. That's why you are seeing both in the same bar.

Comment: Oh right. Yeah, I forgot about paragon and renegade actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The blue wings represent the portion of your reputation that has come from Paragon actions. Conversely, the red star represents the portion of your reputation that has come from Renegade actions.